# Child element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem in closing the .panel-body of my Bootstrap panel when I click on the .panel-header.

I have three BS Panels in a row so, when I click one, all are closing immediatly.

The thing that I want is to close the .panel-body of the panel clicked.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will close the panel-body that lives next to the heading you have clicked.

```
$(".panel-heading").on("click", function ( ev ) {

  $(this).siblings(".panel-body").hide();
});
```

And you could use `.toggle()` instead of `.hide()` if you wanted a separate click to re-open this element.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the this object within the scope of the click event,

```
$('.panel-body').click(function() {
    $(this).hide(); //or toggle show/hide with $(this).toggle()
});
```

Comment: $(this).hide(); if you want to hide whole .panel-body or $(this).find('.element-you-want-to-hide').hide();